# What security concerns are there in sharing the SigningCertificate

Tags: identityserver3

I know the IdentityServerOptions.SigningCertificate is used to sign the tokens provided by IDS.  Are there any concernes if this certificate was available outside of IDS?  Is it possible to craft an access token if you have access to this certificate?

We have a product we were wondering if we should ship a premade certifcate inside the msi installer, or we need to ship the sdk (or makecert) to generate a unique one for each client.  Obviously the easiest option is to ship a pre-prepared one, just want to understand the risks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it you're going to be distributing a copy of IdentityServer with your system so you'll have lots of installations out there each with its own IdentityServer.

Basically IdentityServer needs to have access to the private key in order to sign its tokens so if you supply the same certificate+private key for all installations then in theory one installation could trust the tokens from another. Obviously the content of the tokens is also relevant but seeing as this is your system it's not so unlikely that scopes, claims, etc could make sense across installations.

If you add a malicious person into the mix then they could simply choose the contents of the token and sign it, they could even use the IdentityServer code itself to do this as it's open source.

You should look into allowing administrators to load a pfx file or configure a signing certificate that exists in a certificate store. There are various gotchas to both approaches, this blog post has some good info about problems you may encounter:

http://paulstovell.com/blog/x509certificate2

You'll also want to consider how you renew certificates, IdentityServer has good support for this, info in the docs here:

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/crypto.html

Edit:

In case my initial assumption is incorrect and there will only be one IdentityServer which will be under your control and you'll only distribute the public key then that's fine! Here's a good explanation of public vs private keys and terminology:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29425/difference-between-pfx-and-cert-certificates

Comment: Thanks @Matt.  This reaffirmed my fears with this approach.  Looks like a unique certificate is the solution here.